# How can I trigger an element to 'click' IF it is currently selected through tabbing on the keyboard?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an identical dropdown menu for each of 5 div boxes. I want to create functionality where when I navigate to one of these dropdown menus, that is via tabbing to the chevron down icon shown in the code below,  I can expand and collapse the menu that is currently in focus.

```
<div class="appExperience small-tile">
<div class="blue-bar">
<h2 class="tile-header">APPLICATION EXPERIENCE</h2>
<span class="dropdown hidden-xs">
    <i class="tcm-chevron glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down expand-icon dropdown-toggle"
       role="button"
       aria-labledby="Expand Application Experience Summary Dropdown Menu"
       ng-src="{{dropdown_appExperience}}"
       data-toggle="dropdown"
       tabindex="0"
       alt="Expand Application Experience Summary Dropdown Menu"></i>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu appExperience tileContextMenu">
        <li>
       List Item 1
        </li>
        <li>
       List Item 2
        </li>
         ...
```

I have tried this following:

```
 $(window).on("keydown", function() {

        $('.glyphicon-chevron-down option:selected').trigger("click")
  });
```

**Edit, this is another new attempt**

```
  if ($(".glyphicon-chevron-down").is(":focus")) {
        $(window).on("keydown", function() {
            $(".glyphicon-chevron-down").trigger("click") 
        });
    }
```

**Newest attempt**
I'm getting close, but the following code suggests that trigger is not a function?

```
 $(window).on("keydown", function() {

    console.log(document.activeElement);
    console.log($(".glyphicon-chevron-down")[0]);

   if (document.activeElement == $(".glyphicon-chevron-down")[0])  {
       console.log("activeElement is recognized!")   
        console.log($(".glyphicon-chevron-down")[0]);
         $(".glyphicon-chevron-down")[0].trigger("click");
       }
```

});

Comment: `.glyphicon-chevron-down option:selected'` - where is your `option` element in HTML?

Comment: Can you please post a working fiddle for whatever you have? It will be easy for us to debug and resolve

Comment: The "return" key already does that in most browsers -- I.e. "clicks" the selected element that you have tabbed to -- the spacebar, however have a scroll to next page by default, and tab etc has a goto next field -- It is probably bad design to try to remap the semantics, and ironically if you are trying to map all keys to mean "click" you would no longer be able to "tab" -- so not sure I fully understand the question and what you are trying to do.

Comment: see the new attempt above. I want to make an element clickable if it is the active element/has focus

Comment: @KunalOjha  you new attemp will declare the key down function once the class is in focus, and that even will be permantly on there, which you don't want.  What you want to to listen for the tab key on your key down, and count your tab indexes if the next tab index is the element you want focus then fire  your trigger click.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think you need to track the tab event as:  `$(".glyphicon-chevron-down").focus(function(){});` , would do the job without the extra event for tracking the user "tab" button pressing.

Try:

```
$(".glyphicon-chevron-down").focus( function(){
   //do your logic here
   //e.g
   $( this ).trigger("click"); // if this should expand on hover then bind hover event
   // hover event
   $( this ).trigger("mouseover");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the element that is currently in focus. You can then work with it according to your preference.

```
$(window).on("keyup", function() {
    console.log(document.activeElement);
});
```

Comment: This seems to be an element off / behind, in other words it seems to show the perviously active element as the "active" one.

Comment: @HlawuM just updated the answer. Changed the keydown to keyup.

Comment: @pparas this is going to fire if your just typing in a text box, you should be checking for the tab key.

Comment: @pparas Ok. I still feel there's no need to bind window to any event to achieve the results.

Comment: @HlawuM I agree. I think your answer makes complete sense.